# SQL: GROUP BY column B for groups in column a

Tags: sql, group-by, heidisql

I am looking for a SQL query that will sum the values in column C GROUP BY column B, but not over the entire table, only within the ranges where the same values are present in column A.

Current table:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 10 |
| A | B | 5 |
| A | B | 8 |
| A | C | 1 |
| A | D | 7 |
| B | B | 10 |
| B | B | 5 |

Required table:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 23 |
| A | C | 1 |
| A | D | 7 |
| B | B | 15 |

SELECT A, B, SUM(C)
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY B

This obviously doesn't work, because I don't use column A with an aggregate function, nor in the GROUP BY statement. How do I get to the desired solution? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try select a, b, sum(c) as c from yourtable group by a, b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to group by the first two columns and sum the third:

```sql
SELECT A, B, SUM(C) AS SUM_C,
       100.0 * SUM(C) / SUM(SUM(C)) OVER (PARTITION BY A) AS PCT
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY A, B;
```

Comment: That worked thank you! Is there a way to double "group by"? As now i need a new column D, that gives me the percentage share of the individual values in column C in the total of the values in column C within the group for which the values in column A are the same. The result desired would be:

Column D:

74,1%
3.2%
22.5%
100%

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. next I tried to sum up the values in my tabel for each PARTITION BY A using GROUPING SETS. MY QUERY looks like this:

SELECT A, B, SUM(C) AS SUM_C,
       100.0 * SUM(C) / SUM(SUM(C)) OVER (PARTITION BY A) AS PCT
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((A, B), (A));

It works as intened, inserting a row that sums up my partition. But somehow all my values are cut in half? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please consider _accepting_ this answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left.  For more follow ups, maybe ask a new question.

Comment: Accepted it. Thank you! Do you know why my SUM(SUM(C)) OVER (PARTITION BY A) AS PCT ist twice as big after my grouping sets statement?

Comment: I actually have not worked much with `GROUPING SETS`...but maybe you don't even need to be using it.

Answer (score -2):

You can do nested grouping. The first column in the order gets to group the result first and the following columns get grouped within the group of the previous group.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table GROUP BY A, B;
```

Comment: Your query will produce one column only, OP requested three.